# Split Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

Is there a way of changing my array of objects into a few seperate arrays for each property of my objects?

For example, I have this:

```
[ 
    { 
        date: Mon Aug 08 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST),
        visits: 0,
        hits: 578,
        views: 5131 
    },
    { 
        date: Tue Aug 09 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST),
        visits: -1,
        hits: 548,
        views: 722 
    },
    { 
        date: Wed Aug 10 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST),
        visits: -1,
        hits: 571,
        views: 4772 
    }
]
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
var dates = ["date1", "date2", ...],
    visits = ["visit1", "visit2", ...],
    hits = ["hits1", "hits2", ...],
    views = ["view1", "view2", ...];
```

So that I can use it with [plot.ly.](https://plot.ly/)

Comment: Why aren't for loops intelligent?

Comment: I think you would need to use one loop iterating over the objects in the initial array and then populate the arrays for dates, hits etc

Comment: @EatPeanutButter, i meant the js version of the pythonic ways :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
var array =  [ { "date": 'Mon Aug 08 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST)',
    visits: 0,
    hits: 578,
    views: 5131 },
  { "date": 'Tue Aug 09 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST)',
    visits: -1,
    hits: 548,
    views: 722 },
  { "date": 'Wed Aug 10 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST)',
    visits: -1,
    hits: 571,
    views: 4772 }];

var dates = array.map(item => item.date);
var visits = array.map(item => item.visits);
var hits = array.map(item => item.hits);
var views = array.map(item => item.views);

console.log(dates, visits, hits, views);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` and destructuring

```js
var arr = [
  { date: "Mon Aug 08 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST)", visits: 0, hits: 578, views: 5131 },
  { date: "Tue Aug 09 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST)", visits: -1, hits: 548, views: 722 },
  { date: "Wed Aug 10 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST)", visits: -1, hits: 571, views: 4772 }
];

let keys = ['date','visits','hits','views'],
    [dates, visits, hits, views] = arr.reduce( (a,b) => {
 return keys.map( (x,i) => {a[i].push(b[x])}), a;
}, [[],[],[],[]]);

console.log(dates, visits, hits, views)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top: 0; max-height: 100%!important}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterating the array and push the same keys to the same key in an object.

This answer utilized an object, opposite of the wanted results in single variables. The advantage is to keep all data combined and not spreaded over the code in different variable.

The use is easy with just the reference by property.

```js
var data = [{ "date": 'Mon Aug 08 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST)', visits: 0, hits: 578, views: 5131 }, { "date": 'Tue Aug 09 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST)', visits: -1, hits: 548, views: 722 }, { "date": 'Wed Aug 10 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST)', visits: -1, hits: 571, views: 4772 }],
    object = { date: [], visits: [], hits: [], views: [] },
    keys = Object.keys(object);

data.forEach(function (a) {
    keys.forEach(function (k) {
       object[k].push(a[k]);
    });
});

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it will be difficult to make without loop.

This code might be simpler:

```
var data =  [
{ date: "Mon Aug 08 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST)", visits: 0, hits: 578, views: 5131 },
{ date: "Tue Aug 09 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST)", visits: -1, hits: 548, views: 722 },
{ date: "Wed Aug 10 2016 16:59:16 GMT+0200 (CEST)", visits: -1, hits: 571, views: 4772 }
];

var getArrayByValue = function(data, key) {
    var result = [];
    for (i in data) {
        result.push(data[i][key])
    }
    return result;
}

var dates = getArrayByValue(data, 'date')
var visits = getArrayByValue(data, 'visits')
var hits = getArrayByValue(data, 'hits')
var views = getArrayByValue(data, 'views')
```